# Magento SOAP order failes with message "birthday is required"

Tags: php, magento

I use this code to create an order through the `magento` (1.9) `soap api` v2.

The problem is, that I have to do this for a site, where the dob (day of birth) is a required field. Therefor I do get an error message - on that site - "birthday is required".

Do anybody know how to solve that problem (without disabling the dob as required field)?

```
$storeId = '1';

$quoteId = $client->shoppingCartCreate($session,$storeId);

echo "<br>Quote ID : " . $quoteId;

/* Set cart customer */
$guest = true;

if ($guest) 
{
    $customerData = array(
        "firstname" => "testFirstname",
        "lastname" => "testLastName",
        "email" => "testEmail@mail.com",
        "mode" => "guest",
        "website_id" => "1"
    );
} 
else 
{
    $customer  = array(
        "customer_id" => '69301',
        "website_id" => "1",
        "group_id" => "1",
        "store_id" => "1",
        "mode" => "customer",
    );
}

//Set cart customer (assign customer to quote)
$resultCustomerSet = $client->shoppingCartCustomerSet($session, $quoteId, $customerData,$storeId);

echo "<br>Set Customer: ";
var_dump($resultCustomerSet);   //Set customer

/* Set customer addresses Shipping and Billing */

$addresses = array(
    array(
        "mode" => "shipping",
        "firstname" => "Ahsan",
        "lastname" => "testLastname",
        "company" => "testCompany",
        "street" => "testStreet",
        "city" => "Karachi",
        "region" => "Sindh",
        "postcode" => "7502",
        "country_id" => "PK",
        "telephone" => "0123456789",
        "fax" => "0123456789",
        "is_default_shipping" => 0,
        "is_default_billing" => 0
    ),
    array(
        "mode" => "billing",
        "firstname" => "Ahsan",
        "lastname" => "testLastname",
        "company" => "testCompany",
        "street" => "testStreet",
        "city" => "Karachi",
        "region" => "Sindh",
        "postcode" => "7502",
        "country_id" => "PK",
        "telephone" => "0123456789",
        "fax" => "0123456789",
        "is_default_shipping" => 0,
        "is_default_billing" => 0
    )
);

//Set cart customer address
$resultCustomerAddress = $client->shoppingCartCustomerAddresses($session, $quoteId, $addresses,$storeId);   

echo "<br>Set Customer Address: ";
var_dump($resultCustomerAddress);   //Set customer addresses

/* Add products to cart */
$product = array(
                            'product_id' => '905',
                            // 'sku' => 'simple_product',
                            'qty' => '1',
                            'options' => null,
                            'bundle_option' => null,
                            'bundle_option_qty' => null,
                            'links' => null);
$product2 = array(
                            'product_id' => '904',
                            // 'sku' => 'simple_product',
                            'qty' => '2',
                            'options' => null,
                            'bundle_option' => null,
                            'bundle_option_qty' => null,
                            'links' => null);

$addToCart = $client->shoppingCartProductAdd($session, $quoteId, array($product,$product2),$storeId);

echo "<br>Add to Cart: ";
var_dump($addToCart);

/* Set payment method */
$responsePayment = $client->shoppingCartPaymentMethod($session, $quoteId, array(
    'method' => 'cashondelivery',
),$storeId);  

echo "<br>Set Payment method: ";
var_dump($responsePayment);

/* Set shipping method */
$setShipping = $client->shoppingCartShippingMethod($session, $quoteId, 'flatrate_flatrate',$storeId);

echo "<br>Set Shipping method: ";
var_dump($setShipping);

/* Set Discount Code */

try
{
    $result = $client->shoppingCartCouponAdd($session, $quoteId, 'test123',$storeId);
    echo "<br>Apply discount code: ";
    var_dump($result);
}
catch(Exception $ex)
{
    echo "<br>Discount code Failed: " . $ex->getMessage();
    die();
}


$orderId = $client->shoppingCartOrder($session, $quoteId, $storeId, null);
echo "<br>Placed Order: ";
var_dump($orderId);
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Youre say youre getting an error message "birthday is required" because the system environment demands a birthday to run orders. Your code doesnt define any birthdate when trying place an order. Therefore the system doesnt place the order but gives you the errormessage. From the given point of view, your system works correct.

Comment: The problem is, that I do not know how to add the bod to the api request...
If I add 'bod' to the $customerData - it does not have any effect. 

Although http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/checkout/cartCustomer/cart_customer.set.html states out, that the shoppingCartCustomerEntity have no bod field.

Comment: The CartCustomer does include a customer_id which points to a customer (http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/customer/customer.info.html) which holds a field named "bod". Maybe thats your missing field ?

Comment: But it should work as a "guest" order. Anybody know how to do it?

Comment: You cant if bod is madatory i guess.